# Migrating SOAP service client to .NET 8

Tags: soap, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I am migrating a .NET Framework WPF app to .NET 8. In my app, I have a service reference to a SOAP service so I have to migrate that as well.

I created a new project, added a service reference for a WCF Web service, it generate the Reference file and I have all my methods.

First thing all the Guid as been replaced by string for interoperability from what I understand from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60458784/why-guid-is-replaced-by-string-at-generation-of-proxy-class-for-wsdl), which I don't really understand since my API is clearly returning Guid in the type then I check the `.asmx` file.

But oh well I can do with parsing guids, but now I have a parsing error on the server :

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The server was unable to read the request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML document (1, 410).
>
> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.
>
> at System.Guid.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String failureArgumentName, Exception innerException)
> at System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result)
> at System.Guid..ctor(String g)
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read3_NullableOfGuid(Boolean checkType)
> at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read34_AddInformation()
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
> at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

It obviously work with the .NET Framework service ref, so what is different in .NET 8? Are they compatible? Is there some other steps to do to ensure the Reference are correctly generated?

Comment: Also generating the Reference.cs file with a .NET Framework project and then copy pasting it into the .NET 8 project work just fine, there is my Guid no more parse error ... is the .NET 8 SOAP service generation bugged ?